# Hitting Gmail smtp server using C# but getting few errors. Please suggest

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, smtp, smtpclient

I am trying to hit gmail smtp server from my C# web application, But getting following errors : 
1) Failure Sending Message 
2) "The operation has timed out."

Following is my code,

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        string msg = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(from);
            message.From = fromAddress;
            message.To.Add(to);

            message.Subject = Name;
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            message.Body = "Some Message";
            smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";   // We use gmail as our smtp client
            smtpClient.Port = 465; //587 for TLS 465 or 25 SSL
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(from, fromPassword);
            smtpClient.Timeout = 50000;
            smtpClient.Send(message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("InnerException is: {0}", ex.InnerException);
            }
        }
```

Please Suggest i have tried using Port 587 as well, but both showing the same error.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://www.emailarchitect.net/easendmail/kb/csharp.aspx?cat=2) link below in greatest details explains how you can do this (in several ways)

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SmtpMail oMail = new SmtpMail("TryIt");
            SmtpClient oSmtp = new SmtpClient();

            // Your gmail email address
            oMail.From = "gmailid@gmail.com";

            // Set recipient email address
            oMail.To = "support@emailarchitect.net";

            // Set email subject
            oMail.Subject = "test email from gmail account";

            // Set email body
            oMail.TextBody = "this is a test email sent from c# project with gmail.";

            // Gmail SMTP server address
            SmtpServer oServer = new SmtpServer("smtp.gmail.com");

            // Set 465 port
            oServer.Port = 465;

            // detect SSL/TLS automatically
            oServer.ConnectType = SmtpConnectType.ConnectSSLAuto;

            // Gmail user authentication
            // For example: your email is "gmailid@gmail.com", then the user should be the same
            oServer.User = "gmailid@gmail.com";
            oServer.Password = "yourpassword";

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("start to send email over SSL ...");
                oSmtp.SendMail(oServer, oMail);
                Console.WriteLine("email was sent successfully!");
            }
            catch (Exception ep)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("failed to send email with the following error:");
                Console.WriteLine(ep.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: post relevant portions of link rather a link to avoid downvotes